# Display hidden div on a:hover

Tags: html, css

I have done this with menu/sub-menu but can't seem to get this working when doing it for a slightly different reason.

I have the following  which is an info graphic, and a hidden div with some text in:

```
<div class="basictext">
<p>This package allows you to "buy" a customisable web template from us to host on your own web hosting and register your own domain name for.</p>
</div>
<li class="title basic">Basic<br/><a></a></li>
```

In my css, .basictext is hidden (but styled), and when .basic a is hovered .basictext should display with display:block

`.basictext {display: none; height: 60px; width: 130px; border: 2px solid #1572b8; background: #fff; padding: 10px;}
.basic a:hover .basictext   {display: block;}`

It's just not appearing at all, any help please?

Comment: Where is the `a`? There is a single `a` in your code, but it doesn't have attributes or content. Also, by your description, there should be an `a` around the whole snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.basic a:hover .basictext   {display: block;}
```

Will affect an element with 'basictext' class that's inside an a tag that's inside an element with the class 'basic'.

```
<div class="basictext">
    <a> <span class="basictext">Will appear when hovering</span> </a>
</div>
```

Your html is not structured that way, that's why the rule doesn't catch.

Comment: OK thanks, so I have put the "basictext" div inside the 'a', this is the hidden div to display on hover.

`<li class="title basic"><h2>Basic</h2>
<a><div class="basictext">
<p>This package allows you to "buy" a customisable web template from us to host on your own web hosting and register your own domain name for.</p>
</div></a></li>`

CSS

`.basictext {display: none; height: 60px; width: 130px; border: 2px solid #1572b8; background: #fff; padding: 10px;}
.basic a:hover .basictext {display: block;}`

Comment: I would recommend not putting a block element (such as a <div>) inside an inline element (such as an <a>).

Also my guess is that hovering over the <a> tag would be impossible since there's nothing inside of it (other than the hidden content).

Try this - <div class="hoverOverMe"> <span>Hover here</span> <div class="basictext">Hidden content here</div> </div>

and change the a from your css rule to .hoverOverMe